# Expected length of time until the mouse reaches the compost heap.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm assuming it's a Markov Chain question but I have no idea how to do this.  Thanks in advance!

> A mouse lives in a mousehole with three exits.
>
> - The first exit leads
>     to a compost heap after 1 minute of scurrying.
> - The second exit leads
>     to a tunnel that returns it to the mousehole after three minutes.
> - The third exit leads to a tunnel that returns it to the mousehole after four
>     minutes.
>
> Assume the mouse has no memory of previous excursions
>   when it returns to its mousehole, and is always equally likely to choose
>   any one of the exits, what is the expected length of time until the
>   mouse reaches the compost heap?

[The scan of the original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WJPG.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $E$ be the desired expected time. Can you explain why $$E = \frac{1}{3}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{3}(3+E) +  \frac{1}{3}(4+E),$$
and hence deduce the value of $E$?

Comment: can't believe it's actually that easy... Thanks! E=8 is what I got, hopefully it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

More difficult way! Refer to the table, where $X$ is the number of minutes:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Excursions ($n$)}&X&P(X)&XP(X)\\
\hline
1&1&1/3&1\cdot 1/3\\
\hline
2&3+1&1/3^2&(3+1)\cdot 1/3^2\\
2&4+1&1/3^2&(4+1)\cdot 1/3^2\\
\hline
3&3+3+1&1/3^3&(3+3+1)\cdot 1/3^3\\
3&3+4+1&1/3^3&(3+4+1)\cdot 1/3^3\\
3&4+3+1&1/3^3&(4+3+1)\cdot 1/3^3\\
3&4+4+1&1/3^3&(4+4+1)\cdot 1/3^3\\
\hline
4&3+3+3+1&1/3^4&(3+3+3+1)\cdot 1/3^4
\\
\vdots\end{array}$$
$$\mathbb E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty XP(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((n-1)\cdot 2^{n-2}\cdot 7+2^{n-1})\cdot \frac1{3^{n}}=8.$$
Wolframalpha [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5Einfty%20((n-1)%5Ccdot%202%5E%7Bn-2%7D%5Ccdot%207%2B2%5E%7Bn-1%7D)%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac1%7B3%5E%7Bn%7D%7D).

Comment: why the downvote? is it incorrect or is it too difficult? any comments?